# Create functions within classes in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, class

I was trying to include my own functions in mainpage class, but when calling them it's not working at all, so what i did is to create a class for it and included that function in it. and in get () of mainpage class i created an instance for that class and called the function like object_name.function name() but it ain't working

```
class encipher:
    def time_stomp():
        t1=time.time()
        dt = datetime.now()
        dt.now()
```

```
        stri=""
        stri+=(str(dt.minute*dt.microsecond)[0:4])
        stri+=(str(dt.second*dt.microsecond)[0:2])
        stri+=(str(dt.microsecond)[0:3])
        stri+=(str(dt.microsecond)[2:3])
        stri+=(str(dt.microsecond)[1:2])
        stri+=(str(dt.microsecond)[0:1])
        return stri

#-------------------------------------------------------------
    def keygen():


        key_stri=""

        ko=0
        datalist_str1=self.time_stomp()
        for i in range(6):

                key_stri+=((hex(operator.xor(int(datalist_str1[ko:ko+2]),128)).replace("0x","")).zfill(2))
                ko+=2
                #print "Key:",key_stri

                #print "Key:",key_stri
        #print "Key:",key_stri
        return key_stri
```

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):

def get(self):
    ddes=encipher()
    global final_data_hex
    global username
    global filename
    username = self.request.get("name")
    filename=self.request.get("filename")
    addr=self.request.get("mac")
    path="d:/xampp/htdocs/encrypt/"+username+'/'+filename
    f1 = open(path, 'r')
    #f1=open(path,"r")
    string=f1.read()
    i=0
    addr=addr.replace(":",'')

    #self.response.out.write(ddes.keygen())

Comment: You've got your indentation wrong, at least in the code snippet, and certainly nothing will work. For instance, keygen() is not defined as a member function of the encipher class. So far as this is not just a typo in the code snippet, your question is not google-app-engine specific.

Comment: The intendation is perfect in app engine..... is there a method we can include our function within the mainpage class

Comment: We really need more details than "ain't working". What happens? And what was wrong with making them standalone functions, or methods on the handler class?

Comment: @Nick: The functions did not work when i made a class for them. But makin them standalone works now!!!!

Comment: Generally speaking you should also be using _new style_ classes `class encipher(object):` and avoid _old style_ classes `class encipher:`

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan Did not work _how_? You need to be more specific than "did not work"!

Answer (score 3):

A python instance method needs to accept at least one parameter, `self`.  "It's not working" is a horrible explanation of a problem; if you'd read your tracebacks you'd see an error about .keygen() accepting 0 arguments with 1 provided.

But yes, there's no reason to encapsulate methods in a class if what you really want is a function.

Comment: It works without givin a (self) parameter, but then i gave the self parameter after your answer. Thank you :)

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan: the parameter is only needed for instance methods; that is, functions defined within a `class` definition. For normal functions, you can have a blank parameter list if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. We can simply include functions out of the class and it will work perfectly.